# Integrating Liferay UI tag in XHTML page

Tags: jsf, liferay

Is there any way to put liferay UI tag in XHTML page (JSF).

For example, I would like to put the following tag (liferay-ui:message key="hello") in XHTML. I have already the JSF webapp but I'm stuck on configurations (xml, etc..) to put this liferay UI tag inside xhtml.

Many thanks for helping me.

Comment: I would assume that is in some basic liferay tutorial???

Answer (score 4):

`liferay-ui:` tags are JSP tags, so they are incompatible with JSF facelets. In order to obtain an internationalized message in a Liferay Faces portlet, you can use [the i18n map feature](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/localizing-jsf-portlets#option-2-using-the-built-in-i18n-keyword-provided-by-liferay-faces-portal) instead: `#{i18n['key']}`.

As of [the release of Liferay Faces Portal `3.0.0`](https://web.liferay.com/web/neil.griffin/blog/-/blogs/announcement-support-for-jsf-in-liferay-portal-7-0-dxp), the Liferay Faces team has created [several `portal:` components](http://liferayfaces.org/web/guest/portal-showcase) to enable the functionality of Liferay's JSP tags in JSF facelets:

- `liferay-ui:captcha` -> `portal:captcha`
- `liferay-ui:input-editor` -> `portal:inputRichText`
- `liferay-ui:search` -> `portal:inputSearch`
- `liferay-ui:header` -> `portal:header`
- `aui:nav` -> `portal:nav`
- `aui:nav-item` -> `portal:navItem`
- `aui:nav-bar` -> `portal:navBar`
- `liferay-security:permissionsURL` -> `portal:permissionsURL`
- `liferay-portlet:runtime` -> `portal:runtime`

Similarly, [Liferay Faces Alloy](http://liferayfaces.org/web/guest/alloy-showcase/) can be used to replace many of the `aui:` tags. Liferay Faces Alloy provides components based on AlloyUI and Bootstrap CSS so they are styled exactly like any built-in Liferay components.

Full Disclosure: I am a member of the Liferay Faces team and have worked on both Liferay Faces Alloy and Portal.

Comment: Thanks. What is the equivalent of liferay-ui:journal-article tag in Liferay faces?

Comment: @OctronMan, there isn't an equivalent. You can request that we add it as a feature: https://issues.liferay.com/secure/CreateIssue.jspa?pid=12081&issuetype=2. You could also try using `portal:runtime` to display a Journal Content Portlet inside your own portlet: http://liferayfaces.org/web/guest/portal-showcase/-/portal-tag/portal/runtime/multiple-instances.

Comment: @OctronMan, or you could [obtain the article content programmatically with `JournalArticle.getContentByLocale()`](https://docs.liferay.com/ce/apps/web-experience/latest/javadocs/com/liferay/journal/model/JournalArticle.html#getContentByLocale-java.lang.String-) and display it with a simple `outputText escape="false"`.